# What happens if I pass in a variable down too many requires()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I'm passing in the `players` variable down 3 levels on my NodeJS folder.

The first file is server.js, which have

```
var players = {};
require('./routines')(players);
```

Inside the routines folder, this is **index.js:**

```
module.exports = function (players) {
  var addHp = require('./addHp')(players);
}
```

Inside the **addHp.js:**

```
module.exports = function (players) {
  var addHp = setInterval ( function () {
    for (var player in players) {
       //...
    }
  }, 30000);
}
```

I want to know what is the performance draw of doing this. The `players` reference is sent only on the initialization of the server? Does it have any downsides on having too many references? Besides bad practice, suppose I have 100 requires inside requires receiving `players`, would I have a problem?

Comment: Why not separate `players` into its own module and require that where you need it?

Comment: players is deeply connected with the full project. This is only a snippet. :)

Comment: If it's a basic js object it shouldn't do much since you're just passing it down if it is an interactive object and you are trying to listen to changes on it then it might be more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a performance standpoint, this really shouldn't be a problem. It's not like we're executing `requires` a million times in a loop. A `require` of even an already-loaded module could be a tad expensive given the lookup cost, but it would have to be in some intensive loop to make that a concern.

Furthermore, with respect to passing a reference to this `players` object down three function calls, it's actually potentially cheaper than having some global. Contrary to common belief, copying a more global variable's contents to a local scope is often as cheap or cheaper than a global variable (provided the copy is cheap, which would be the case for a reference). It's because from the compiler's point of view with something like this:

```
module.exports = function (players) {
  var addHp = require('./addHp')(players);
}
```

... it can assume that this `players` parameter (local to the function) will not reference anything else during that time since it can see, simply within the function, that it is not assigned to anything else during that period.

Because of that, it's easier for the compiler to apply optimizations where it can move this `players` reference once into a register and keep it there without constantly reloading it from a slower form of memory every time it is accessed within the function. Of course a very aggressive optimizer may still avoid that even if `players` was some global, but it's more difficult to make that assumption and it should be safe to say that the local copy of the reference here will be as fast or faster.